# Send user to https:// via htaccess..?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site with a page called checkout.php.  In order to ensure users are always on https:// when they reach this page I added the following to my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout.php
RewriteRule ^(checkout.php)$ https://www.domain.org/checkout.php [L,R=301]
```

That works great.  Now I'm trying to do the same thing for a directory instead of a file.  So instead of www.domain.org/checkout.php it would just be www.domain.org/checkout

I adjusted the .htaccess file so it is like this now...

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout
RewriteRule ^(checkout)$ https://www.domain.org/checkout [L,R=301]
```

That does not seem to be working for me, though, and I'm not sure what adjustments I need to make for this to work with a directory like that.

Any information on how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: ^(checkout)$ mean begin with "checkout" and $ make that it must be end there. so, in case that you try /checkout/ won't be going to this rule. may try `^(checkout)` without $.

Comment: That isn't working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^checkout(/.*)?$ https://www.domain.org/checkout$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect requests to all files under the checkout directory.